# A sticky menu bar, which starts at the bottom and then stays at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, sticky

I'm making this single-page site where on the first opening, the whole screen is filled with a large image, with the menu bar on the bottom of the screen.

When you scroll down, I want the menu to scroll with the content but then stay glued to the top of the window and never slide out of the top edge, in order to always be accessible.

I have found many "sticky menu" scripts that do something close to it, but they always start with the menu bar somewhere in the middle of the page, never a menu that is aligned to the bottom at the start.

Here's a fiddle:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pREYeJ

I used this script in it:
http://stickyjs.com/

Like all others I've tried, it doesn't work as intended. The menu bar fails to slide smoothly as you scroll, it just jumps to the top of the page as soon as you start scrolling.

I think the problem is in the fact I am using

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

on the menu bar's div.

However I don't know how else to achieve it to stick to the bottom of the window, regardless the window size, when you first open the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may add a `transition` and a value for `top` to trigger the `transition` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNKbyE

Comment: Are you looking for something like this site? 
http://www.arketypeinc.com/

Answer (score 3):

[You may add a `top` value and a `transition` in your CSS :](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNKbyE)

```
#menu{
  /* trigger an animation when scripts updates CSS*/
  top:calc(100% - 100px);/* cause scripts gives top:0 and erase bottom */
  transition:1s;/* your transition */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #009900; 
}
```

---

edit

Else, you can inspire yourself from : https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/

for this kind of result http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgEeye

position:fixed instead absolute and here the script updated:

```
//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $("#menu").sticky({topSpacing:0});
//  });

var menu =  document.querySelector('#menu');
var box =  document.querySelector('#screen2');
var boxPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= boxPosition) {
        menu.style.top = '0px';
    } else {
        menu.style.top = 'calc(100% - 100px)';
    }
});
```

```js
var menu =  document.querySelector('#menu');
var box =  document.querySelector('#screen2');
var boxPosition = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= boxPosition) {
        menu.style.top = '0px';
    } else {
        menu.style.top = 'calc(100% - 100px)';
    }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#screen1 {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
#menu {
  transition: 1s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: #009900;
  border-top: 2px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#screen2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f4452a;
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen1">
  screen
</div>
<div id="menu">
  THIS IS THE MENU
  <br />and I don't want to abruptly jump to the top but to gently slide to it on scroll and then stick to it
</div>
<div id="screen2">
  Rest of the page bla bla
  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />  <br />keep scrolling
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmmm. That looks nicer but isn't what I'm after because it moves to the top as soon as you start scrolling. 

I'd like it to stay in the same place - between "screen1" and "screen2", not move to the top over "screen1". 

Well... if I can't find a way to do that I might use your idea though, thanks still :)

Comment: @TinaMalina Well , that's about your script , CSS has nothing to do about when scrolling top is trigered :( , **Maybe you want to add this information in your question** regards

Comment: I may need a different script (I didn't write this one myself, I just googled it up). But I don't know any that work, I've tried a few... :/

Comment: @TinaMalina You may inspire yourself from https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/ doing such http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgEeye